# Proxy server with authentication not working at command line

Tags: command-line, proxy

I'm running Debian 6 in a VM on a network that requires Windows authentication to a proxy server before it can run any http/https/ftp connection.

I've tried:

```
export http_proxy=http://domain\\username:password@proxyIPaddress:8080
```

and same for `ftp_proxy`, but I keep getting: "Proxy server requires authentication".

My password does have a few special characters so I've escaped them using the backslash, just like I do for the domain name. If I hit the up arrow to view my history, the command looks correct (the escape backslashes are gone and the command and password look correct).

What else should I try?

Comment: I think you are colon missing password field.  export http_proxy=http://username**:password**@[IP of Proxy Server]:[port]

Comment: Tejas, I'm sorry, I should have written that. I am including the password. I'll edit the listing above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the `export http_proxy` command as a **string**. This should do the trick:

```
export http_proxy='http://domain\username@proxyIPaddress:8080/'
```

Comment: delta24, still no luck. I did pass it as a string and to confirm, I did "echo $http_proxy" and "echo $ftp_proxy". The strings do appear correct; password, domain, proxy and port.

Comment: then I think your VM network config is not set up correctly. Use **NAT** if you're running **VirtualBox**.

Comment: Dude, that was it. Thank you, you just saved me hours of work. In case anyone else tries this from the command line, special characters in passwords can be escaped using \ such as \@ if @ appears in your password.

Answer (score -1):

```
export http_proxy=domain\\\username:password@proxyIPaddress:port
```

and

```
export https_proxy=domain\\\username:password@proxyIPaddress:port\
```